# Javascript : Split string with RegEx and remove pattern from the array

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to split a string in JAVASCRIPT using regEx,

String to split = `"Base text \n 1. option one  \n 2. Option two \n 3. Option three \n 4. Option four"`

Expected output = `[Base text , option one  , Option two , Option three , Option four]`

But with the regEx I tries I am getting the reg ex in the array as below

`[Base text ,1., option one  ,2., Option two ,3., Option three ,4., Option four]`

RegEx tried - `String.split( new RegExp(/\s*(\d\.|\d\))/g))`

```
String.split( new RegExp("\\s*(\\d\\.|\\d\\))\\s*"))
```

Comment: its better next time to just give us a complete working code segment instead of split up like this.

Comment: Are you trying to match `\d)` too?  Such as 1) Option x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "Base text \n 1. option one  \n 2. Option two \n 3. Option three \n 4. Option four"

var split = str.split (/\s*\n \d\.*\s*/)
console.log (split)

/* OUTPUT:
[
  "Base text",
  "option one",
  "Option two",
  "Option three",
  "Option four"
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this RegEx `/\n \d*\. /`. See the code below which uses this RegEx inside the `split` function.

```js
var str = "Base text \n 1. option one  \n 2. Option two \n 3. Option three \n 4. Option four";

var regex = /\n \d*\. /;

var split_str = str.split(regex);

console.log(split_str);
```